# Sort array by numbers, when the same numbers, sort by alphabet

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, custom-sort

I am trying to solve problem with sorting.
As I´ve written to the title, I need to sort array by numbers, but when some rows have the same number, sort them by alphabet. I was trying to make this with two sorts, but when I use sort by numbers and than second one by alphabet, it doesn't work.. So I've tried to change the order of functions, but still, after number sorting, it doesn't keep alphabetical sort at all...
Could someone tell me what to edit please?

Code below:

```
        $nodesToSort = $this->openedContextMenu->getPreparedNodes();

        $labelSort = function($x, $y)
        {
            $xTranslated = $this->getPresenter()->translator->translate($x->label);
            $yTranslated = $this->getPresenter()->translator->translate($y->label);
            return strcmp($xTranslated, $yTranslated);
        };

        $compareSort = function ($a, $b)
        {
            if ($a->sort == $b->sort) {
                return 0;
            }
            return ($a->sort < $b->sort) ? -1 : 1;
        };

        usort($nodesToSort, $labelSort);
        usort($nodesToSort, $compareSort);
```

Comment: You are very unclear? And makes it any difference when you sort the same value as number or as string? Or from where comes a number and from where comes alphabetic string? Or let me ask it in this way: Is it possible that `sort` has numbers and alphabetic string? And if not, from where comes the alphabetic string that you want to take for sorting.

Comment: Post some sample input and desired output to make it more clear.

Comment: This question is Unclear because there is no [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED.
I just had to merge that two functions.

```
    $compareSort = function ($a, $b)
    {
        if ($a->sort == $b->sort) {
            $xTranslated = $this->getPresenter()->translator->translate($a->label);
            $yTranslated = $this->getPresenter()->translator->translate($b->label);
            return strcasecmp($xTranslated, $yTranslated);
        }
        return ($a->sort < $b->sort) ? -1 : 1;
    };
```